# set multiple delimiter with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, delimiter

I'm doing some simulations in OpenFOAM, using probes to get a time series of the velocity in a point. The output file has the following delimiter setup.

[image]

if it is possible, what would be the command to set the delimiter ?? when using gnuplot

```
set datafile separator '???'
```

Bonus info if I remove all `(` and `)` and use the default command the plot "plots"

```
plot "U" using 1:2
```

Comment: I don't know why the `set datafile separator ' ()\t'` doesn't work though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use `sed` :

```
plot "< sed 's|[()]||g' U" u 1:2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
plot "U" using 1:2 "%lf (%lf %lf %lf)"
```

This format specifies your data format in the plot command.  See `help using` for more details on this and the *using* examples for more complex examples.

If you don't want to type this each time, and you have a copy of gnuplot compiled with support for string macros, you also can do

```
dformat = "\"%lf (%lf %lf %lf)\""
plot "U" using 1:2 @dformat
```

which will expand the format specifier into the command.  See `help macros` for more on this.